# Antlr4 on Windows7 - Parse Tree Inspector doesn't pop up when TestRig is called with -gui switch

Tags: testing, cmd, antlr4

Antlr4 on Windows 7.

Facing issue when running "TestRig with -gui option at cmd with administrative privilege"

CLASSPATH is set as advised on ANtlr site.

"-tokens" and "-tree" TestRig options work fine but "-gui" fails.
With '-gui' switch, parse tree inspector is seen in background but it does'nt pop up and hangs.

Snapshot attached:
[image]

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue (Mac OS in my case) and it seems to have been an issue with the grammar itself. Although grun didn't emit any particular error messages- just as it didn't in your case- I found that by rolling my grammar back to a known "good" configuration (when gui was working before), -gui suddenly started working again.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:
Leave the mouse over the Java icon until the small preview window appears, then move to it, right click and choose the maximize option.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the window containing the tree is not visible or is too small. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Right Click` then maximize. Not sure why windows does that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `Maximize`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just wait a couple minutes and right-click on the Java window (the interface which shows the tree) and choose Minimize.